# What is the order of foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops, foreach

I have an array, for example

```
$arr=array(
    "foo" => "fooval",
    "boo" => "booval",
    "roo" => "rooval",
);
```

and then I want to print all elements in pattern "key is value". This code should do the job:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    echo $key." is ".$val;
```

Will I get this?

```
foo is fooval
boo is booval
roo is rooval
```

I mean the order. Is it guaranteed that it will execute in same order as the array was given, or the arrays are sorted somehow?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Have you tried it? I mean, it's a valid question, you might only get the desired result by chance, but still, it's easy to do some experiments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrays` are ordered list of values and thier orders do not need to be sorted. It follows a sequence

FROM PHP DOC

> An array in PHP is actually an **ordered map.** A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

Answer (score 6):

It will loop through the array in sequential order. So in your specific question you would see the results you expect.